# Read from keyboard non blocking mode because of sockets working, python

Tags: python, sockets, keyboard, nonblocking

Im programming a client-server in python, and them when working are sending keepalive packets every second.

I need the client to read from my keyboard an action to send a special packet to the server, but when reading I can't stop sending keepalive packets, so if I read by standard way, it blocks and stops the keepalive packet sending.

The perfect behaviour would be to write in console while keepaliving, and when pressing "enter" process that text.

Any ideas please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your code. It is bit hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, using select.select I could do that, like this:

```
selectList = [sktTCP,sys.stdin]
(read, write, exc) =  select.select(selectList, [], [], 0 )
```

I hope it'll help someone!

Comment: you can't use `select` with `sys.stdin` on Windows unless it is a socket.

Comment: btw, select is not always reliable with pipes. See [Non-blocking I/O](http://cr.yp.to/unix/nonblock.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a threading issue basically. I would suggest looking into managing your network connections using [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). It can work asynchronously, leaving you able to pick up key presses.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use Twisted and other stuff related because of the requeriments of the project!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to read user input on Unix without blocking (for too long) is to use an alarm:

```
from signal import SIGALRM, alarm, signal

class Alarm(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(*args):
    raise Alarm

def raw_input_alarm(prompt='', timeout=None):
    if timeout is None: # no timeout
        return raw_input(prompt)

    # set signal handler
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    alarm(timeout) # produce SIGALRM in `timeout` seconds
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    except Alarm:
        return '' # timeout happened
    finally:
        alarm(0) # cancel alarm
```

#### Example

```
print(repr(raw_input_alarm(timeout=1)))
```

`alarm` expects integer number of seconds. If you want smaller timeout; see [`signal.setitimer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer).